# What does an empty string key for package_dir do in setup.py?

Tags: python, gradle, setuptools

I have a `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
import setuptools

from distgradle import GradleDistribution

setuptools.setup(
  distclass=GradleDistribution,
  package_dir={'': 'src'},
  packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
  include_package_data=True,
  namespace_packages=['foo'],
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
      'first = foo.something.first:main',
      'second = foo.somethingelse.second:main',
    ],
  },
)
```

What is the significance of `package_dir={'': 'src'}`?  Why do we have an empty string as the key?

Comment: For people googling this question, the Setuptools site has a good explanation, as well.  Basically the empty string is a wildcard that tells it go gather all packages in that directory.  Link:  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout
Note that this reference is for setup.cfg but they do tie it back to the setup.py syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have multiple directories at the root level and under one directory the modules reside, then you can define that directory as root package and then all packages provided to `packages` named argument would be looked up inside that dir. Python's official documentation describes this very well:

> https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages

Here, if code resides under `lib` directory then defining `package_dir = {'': 'lib'}` & `packages = ['foo']` would mean that you are telling that system to look for `foo` module under `lib` i.e. `lib/foo/__init__.py` exists.

Comment: Though your response was correct, that documentation link is for Python 2 and `distutils`, all deprecated long time ago. Python 2 should not be used any more, and the correct link that explains how to pack Python applications nowadays is this: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Great answer! I've updated the link.